# Improving performance for simple left join in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, performance, postgresql, join

I am trying to do a left join between two tables in a postgreSQL database and finding it takes about 14 minutes to run. From existing SO posts, it seems like this type of join should be on the order of seconds, so I'd like to know how to improve the performance of this join. I'm running `64-bit` `postgreSQL version 9.4.4` on a `Windows 8` machine w/ `8 GB RAM`, using `pgAdmin III`. The table structures are as follows:

Table A: "parcels_qtr":

> parcel (text) | yr (int) | qtr (text) | lpid (pk, text) |

Has 15.5 million rows, each column is indexed, and "lpid" is the primary key. I also ran this table through a standard vacuum process.

Table B: "postalvac_qtr":

> parcel (text) | yr (int) | qtr (text) | lpid (pk, text) | vacCountY (int) |

Has 618,000 records, all fields except "vacCountY" are indexed and "lpid" is the primary key. This also has gone through a standard vacuum process.

When running with data output, it takes about 14 min. When running with `explain (analyze, buffers)` it takes a little over a minute. First question - is this difference in performance wholly attributable to printing the data or is something else going on here?

And second question, can I get this run time down to a few seconds?

Here is my SQL code:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
select a.parcel,
   a.lpid,
   a.yr,
   a.qtr,
   b."vacCountY"
from parcels_qtr as a
left join postalvac_qtr as b
on a.lpid = b.lpid;
```

And here are the results of my explain statement: https://explain.depesz.com/s/uKkK

I'm pretty new to postgreSQL so patience and explanations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `yr (int) | qtr (text)` this looks like year and quarter, why not use a date field instead (lose the text field) and perform date_trunc() on it? `all fields except "vacCountY" are indexed and "lpid" is the primary key.` Please learn something about data modelling, a database is not supposed to be a spreadsheet-with-indexes.

Comment: Hey @joop, thanks for the tips on the date field. I'll try that. I added indexes on those other fields because they may be involved in joins in future queries. What resources do you suggest I look at with respect to data modeling? Is there a specific book or tutorial you had in mind?

Comment: It is not clear from your question what your tables *mean*. The parcels_qtr looks like a pre-aggregation of a count field "vacCountY". What is lpid (which is used as a join field). and what does `parcel (text) | yr (int) | qtr (text) | lpid (pk, text) | vacCountY (int) |` mean. Most people here prefer plain sql DDL table definitions to your Klingon notation, IMHP.

Comment: _is this difference in performance wholly attributable to printing the data_: Yes, the query takes 53 seconds and the rest of the time is spent a bit to fetch and mostly to display the results, given that there are 15 million rows.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're asking the DB to do quite a bit of work. Just looking at the explain plan, it's:

1. Read in an entire table (`postalvac_qtr`)
2. Build a hash based on `lpid`
3. Read in an entire other, much larger, table (`parcels_qtr`)
4. Hash each of the 15MM `lpid`s, and match them to the existing hash table

How large are these tables? You can check this by issuing:

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('parcels_qtr'));
```

I'm almost certain that this hash join is spilling out to disk, and the way it's structured ("give me *all* of the data from both of these tables"), there's no way it won't.

The indices don't help, and can't. As long as you're asking for the entirety of a table, using an index would only make things slower -- postgres has to traverse the entire table anyway, so it might as well issue a sequential scan.

As for why the query has different performance than the `explain analyze`, I suspect you're correct. A combination of 1- sending 15M rows to your client, and 2- trying to display it, is going to cause a significant slowdown above and beyond the actual query.

So, what can you do about it?

First, what is this query trying to do? How often do you want to grab *all* of the data in those two tables, completely unfiltered? If it's very common, you may want to consider going back to the requirements stage and figuring out another way to address that need (e.g. would it be reasonable to grab all the data for a given year and quarter instead?). If it's uncommon (say, a daily export), then 1-14min might be fine.

Second, you should make sure that your tables aren't bloated. If you experience significant `update` or `delete` traffic on your tables, that can grow them over time. The autovacuum daemon is there to help deal with this, but occasionally issuing a `vacuum full` will also help.

Third, you can try tuning your DB config. In `postgresql.conf`, there are parameters for things like the expected amount of RAM that your server can use for disk cache, and the amount of RAM the server can use for sorting or joining (before it spills out to disk). By tinkering with these sorts of parameters, you might be able to improve the speed.

Fourth, you might want to revisit your schema. Do you want year and quarter as two separate columns, or would you be better off with a single column of the `date` type? Do you want a `text` key, or would you be better off with a `bigint` (either serial or derived from the `text` column), which will likely join more quickly? Are the `parcel`, `yr`, and `qtr` fields actually needed in both tables, or are they duplicate data in one table?

Anyway, I hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, this is extremely helpful, thanks so much for taking the time to explain. What you mentioned about it doing a table scan makes a lot of sense. I think this would be a fairly infrequent task, so perhaps you're right, that 14 minutes isn't the end of the world. It's good to know that for what I'm trying to do, this isn't an outrageous run time. I'll check out the parameters in the DB config, and play around with data types, as you and @joop suggested. A lot to try out here, thank you!!

Comment: Parker since you are new here,  may i point out that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your reputation).

Comment: Thanks all! Answer accepted! Avoiding displaying the data was probably the biggest help, as was using more appropriate data types.

Comment: If all fields in both tables were indexed we should expect Postgres to choose a merge join and it would perform better, right?

Comment: I wish postgres offered a "hash set join" plan where it would just build a hash set of the lpids in memory, and read the row data from the source table on disk.  I bet it would perform better in a case like this because for 97% of the rows it would quickly determine via memory that there's no matching row, and it would only have to thrash the disk when loading the remaining 3%.  Constantly checking a hash spilled onto disk sounds like a lot more thrashing